# Focusing a ListBoxItem doesn't update its styling

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, attached-properties

A have a ListBox that needs to focus specific items in certain situations (e.g. when showing the results of a search). This is done through an attached property, using the following function:

```
public static void OnElementIndexPropertyChanged (DependencyObject DObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs Args)
  {
  ListBox ListBoxControl = DObject as ListBox;

  if (ListBoxControl != null &&
      (int)Args.NewValue != -1)
    {
    ListBoxControl.ScrollIntoView (ListBoxControl.Items[(int)Args.NewValue]);
    ListBoxControl.UpdateLayout ();

    var ListBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)ListBoxControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem (ListBoxControl.Items[(int)Args.NewValue]);
    ListBoxControl.SelectedItem = ListBoxItem;
    ListBoxItem.Focus ();
    }
  }
```

Now, the ListBoxControl does gain Keyboard focus (if I hold Alt it will show a dotted border around it, and it use the arrow keys to move up/down it works correctly), however, the style is not updated. The last selected item is left with a blue highlight, while the newly selected item isn't updated to show the blue highlight. It only works correctly the first time, before an item is focused and highlighted.

Is there a way around it, beyond manually changing the background/styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ChiuneSugihara, I realized I was setting the `SelectedItem` to the container, and not to the actual item. Changing the line

```
ListBoxControl.SelectedItem = ListBoxItem;
```

to

```
ListBoxControl.SelectedItem = ListBoxItem.Content;
```

was enough to make it work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I am used to the `SelectedItem` being set to an actual item and not the container of that item. It also seems more natural just to use `SelectedIndex` since you already have the index. I was able to get the selection of a `ListBox` working with the style by replacing the `SelectedItem` line with this:

`ListBoxControl.SelectedIndex = (int)Args.NewValue;`

**P.S.**

I should add that maybe I am not fully understanding the question, because I am wondering why you aren't just using `SelectedIndex` instead of a custom attached property to change the selection (maybe because scrolling wouldn't be the same?).

Comment: SelectedIndex was already set, but it wasn't properly focusing the item. So I went for an Attached Property approach. Anyway, your content led me to realize I was setting the `SelectedItem` to the container and not the content. I used `ListBoxItem.Content` and now it works properly.